# Get rows within last 30 days, excluding today

Tags: sql, postgresql, intervals, date-arithmetic

30 days interval with Postgres 9.2.

I have a table like this:

```
ID NAME CREATED_AT

1 valid 2019-03-07 12:00:00
2 valid 2019-02-05 12:00:00
3 valid 2019-02-04 12:00:00
```

I want to get all rows that match 30 days interval *before* today.

If today is 2019-03-07 I should get only:

```
2 valid 2019-02-05 12:00:00
```

If today is 2019-04-06 I should get:

```
1 valid 2019-03-07 12:00:00
2 valid 2019-02-05 12:00:00
```

and so on ...

If today is 2019-05-06:

```
1 valid 2019-03-07 12:00:00
2 valid 2019-02-05 12:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you can just subtract an `integer` (as number of days) from a `date`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  created_at >= current_date - 30
AND    created_at <  current_date;  -- to exclude "today" (and the future)
```

The `date` is cast to `timestamp` implicitly in the expression.

Excluding "today", that makes 30 days. If the table is big, consider an index on `(created_at)`.

Comment: This doesnt work because I should only get results which are exactly in 30 days interval . Lets assume I have a script that should be executed every 30 days like subscription, basically every 30 days from the beginning. So 30 days 60 days etc..

Comment: Updated according to your updated definition of bounds.

Comment: I agree with `current_date`, but think that `- interval '30 day'` is a better recommendation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Better how? Shorter? No. Faster? No. More correct? No. Less Postgres-specific, more standard SQL? Yes. Better readability? Maybe.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter . . . More explicit in the intention.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

```
select (NOW() - interval '30 day')
```

**NOW()** function will return current date.

**INTERVAL** data type allows you to store and manipulate a period of time in years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds, etc. Interval requires 16 byte storage.

```
@ interval [ fields ] [ (p) ]
```

Interval has an optional precision value p. p has range from 0 to 6 and fractions of digits in seconds. @ sign is optional.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE CREATED_AT >= (NOW() - interval '30 day')
AND CREATED_AT <= (NOW() - interval '1 day');
```